# Test First row of matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

What is a good way to test the first row of a Matrix to check if one of the values equal a value. For instance, In this example, I want to get vector in the second row that has the bigger value in the first row, 10.

I can quickly do it with a lop, but don't think it's the best way...

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `MemberQ[m[[1]],n]` ?

Comment: What does `bigger value` mean in `I want to get vector in the second row that has the bigger value` ?

Comment: I meant that in the example, I want to know that the bigger value is 10, and therefor the vector I'm interested in is {1,1,1}. In another example of a 3x3, the values at the first row may be 1, 4, 3 and I need to detect that the bigger value is now in position 2 (number 4), and will use that to get the vector in the second row, below the number 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data**

```
m = {{10, -2, 1}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}}}
```

---

**Code**

This gives the vector in row 2 that is opposite (i.e. under) the largest value (or first of multiple largest values) in row 1:

```
m[[2, Position[m[[1]], Max[m[[1]]]][[1, 1]]]]
```

> {1, 2, 3}

---

**Analysis**

`Max[m[[1]]]` gives the largest value in row 1: `10`

`Position[m[[1]], Max[m[[1]]]][[1, 1]]` gives the column of interest: `1`

Answer (score 3):

So for your general question you will want to use Position/Extract, let say for the example you give to get the vector that corresponds to 1 (which is neither the largest, nor the smallest ...) you could do:

```
Extract[mat[[2, All]], Position[mat[[1, All]], 1]]
```

Now if you want to generally get results that deal with numeric ordering, you can use b.gatessucks answer, or the one I prefer is:

```
mat[[2, Ordering[mat[[1, All]], -1]]]
```

Where -1 gives the largest value, 1 gives the smallest, and any other integer gives the relative largest/smallest (if negative)

Answer (score 2):

If you define your input as

```
matrix = {{10, -2, 1}, {a, b, c}};
```

then you can do

```
Last@Last@SortBy[Transpose[matrix], #[[1]] &]
```

Comment: A variant is to use `Ordering`:  `Last@(Transpose@mat)[[Last@Ordering@First@mat]]`

Answer (score 1):

The question of taking (or applying a transformation to) some part of a rectangular array based on the ordering of another part has come up in many variations. It is related to the general concept of **`Concomitants of order statistics`**
(see, for example, [Yang](https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1176343954)).

Using the built-in function `Ordering` (as in Gabriel's answer), one can define a function to extract the  concomitants in a dataset as follows:

```
concomitantRows[list_, cols_, ordcol_, ranks_, orderingF_: Less] := 
  Part[list[[All, cols]], Ordering[list[[All, ordcol]], ranks, orderingF]]
```

which takes a `list`, and extracts `cols` **associated** with the `ranks` in the `ordcol` using the ordering function `orderingF`.

```
testdata = {RandomSample[Range[6]], RandomChoice[Range[5], 3] & /@ Range[6], 
  RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "F"], 2] & /@ Range[6], RandomSample[Range[6]]};
Transpose@testdata // Grid
```

[image]

Take the rows in the sub-array formed by columns `{2,3,4}` associated with the `top 2` elements in `col 1` based on default ordering `Less`:

```
concomitantRows[Transpose@testdata, {2, 3, 4}, 1, 2]
(* Out[] = {{{3, 3, 4}, {"B", "D"}, 5}, {{4, 4, 1}, {"C", "C"}, 4}} *)
```

Take the ones associated with the third element:

```
concomitantRows[Transpose@testdata, {2, 3, 4}, 1, {3}]
(* Out[] = {{{1, 1, 5}, {"A", "B"}, 3}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `Pick[]` for the purpose:

```
m = {{10, -2, 1}, {{1, 1, 1}, {-3, 1, 3}, {1, -2, 1}}};

First@Pick[Last[#], First[#], Max[First[#]]] &@m
   {1, 1, 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be better to use something like `Association`, but since this question is from 2012, but `Association` is introduced in 2014 :P https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn100

```
{{10, -2, 1}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}}} // 
MapThread[Rule] //
Association //
#[Max[Keys[#]]]&
```